# Implementing inherited interface from a parent that has an inherited interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Suppose I have the following 3 interfaces (format is designed for brevity):

```
public interface ISecondary { }

public interface ITertiary { }

public interface IRoot
{
    public ISecondary secondary
    public ITertiary tertiary
}
```

I have the secondary and tertiary classes which inherit their respective interfaces (formatting is desinged for brevity):

```
public class Secondary : ISecondary { }

public class Secondary2 : ISecondary { }

public class Tertiary : ITertiary { }

public class Tertiary2 : ITertiary { }
```

I would like to be able to impliment the implimented classes into the root class that impliments both interfaces, something like:

```
public class Root : IRoot
{
    public Secondary secondary { get; set; }
    public Tertiary tertiary { get; set; }
    public string foo { get; set; } // This wouldn't need to be cross-compatible
}

public class Root2 : IRoot
{
    public Secondary2 secondary { get; set; }
    public Tertiary2 tertiary { get; set; }
    public double bar { get; set; } // This wouldn't need to be cross-compatible either
}
```

I would then want to do something like (sorry, reflection is not my strong suit):

```
Root root = new Root();
// data is entered

Root2 root2 = new Root(IRoot root)

// Similar to how ObservableCollection can retrieve data
// from a List of the same generic type. This constructor
// would take data from the IRoot properties and put it into root2.
```

So that all members of IRoot are transferred from root to root 2.

Doing this in C# will lead to a matching-type error (CS0738).

In other words (and I apologize if this is hard to understand) I'd like my root interface to use the signatures from the secondary and tertiary interfaces in the HAS-A relationship that my IRoot interface will have, but when implementing the Root class, I'd like to implement their respective inherited classes as well, and not have to use the actual interface.

Thank you kindly for your time.

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to develop an "interface hierarchy" so that I can design data model templates and easily move data across different class types that implement that interface. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are there going to be more than one implementation of `IRoot`? How would the consumer of `IRoot` use it?

Comment: Yacoub: Yes, there will be more than one implementation of IRoot. Think of 2 data models being cross-compatible. One implementation could be a template that has partial data that another implementation with more variables could obtain information from.

Comment: Would the consumer of `IRoot` know that it is speaking with a `Root` object that contains a property of type `Secondary` instead of `ISecondary`? The whole point of interfaces is to hide the implementation details.

Comment: Yacoub: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I've updated the question hopefully more clearly define what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: It is all about the code that is going to use `IRoot`. Can you show a sample of the code that is going to use `IRoot`?

Comment: That definition for IRoot won't compile. Something like this might be doable, but the question is what should to happen if say Root is set to use a Secondary2. That would be compatible with the IRoot interface, but sounds like it would not be allowed by your models. Is an exception at runtime acceptable in this scenario?

Comment: Yacoub: I've updated the question. You'll see that I've added a variable to each extended class that are distinct from each other. This could also include methods. Hopefully that would make things clearer.

Comment: mike z: If needs be, I could try to use a try-catch, but I'd like to avoid exceptions if I can :-)

Comment: @TheDon, as I said before, it all depends on the code that will uses `IRoot`. Without seeing such code, all what anyone can do is guess.

Comment: Ok, but I think it would be considered odd if a setter just didn't do anything when it failed. Does IRoot really need setters for secondary and tertiary?

Comment: @Yacoub: Code has been added, hopefully this will show some purpose. Feel free to ask more questions if anything is unclear.

Comment: @mike z - I'm not an expert in accessors or mutators, but would removing the setters solve the problem?

Comment: You cannot cast `root` to `Root2`. In the code you provided, your are not using `IRoot`. Just `Root` and `Root2`. Maybe you don't need the interface? Do you need ploymorphism?  Is there some code that depends on `IRoot` that could be given `Root` or `Root2` and that wouldn't care which one you give it?

Comment: Without setters, I thought a possible solution was explicit interface implementation. However with that last update, I'm not sure what you want. You can't have one class be automagically converted into another. Either you write a method to do the conversion or you use a library like Automapper.

Comment: @YacoubMassad - IRoot would not have any methods, only properties, so I don't believe I would care which of the extensions would use those methods. Does this make sense?

Comment: Not sure. Without a very clear example of how you are going to use the `IRoot` and its implementations. I can only guess.

Comment: @YacoubMassad - I'm sorry I can't provide a more detailed code, but I have modified the final block of code from a cast to a constructor overload that can take an IRoot type and clone the properties. Do you think that would move the necessary properties from one extension of IRoot to another, depending on which extension has the constructor?

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand what you are trying to do. I cannot help.

Comment: It is OK, you were very helpful. Thank you @YacoubMassad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Root` implements `IRoot` and `IRoot` requires properties of interfaces types, you **must** declare these properties as interfaces in `Root`.

```
public class Root : IRoot
{
    public ISecondary secondary { get; set; }
    public ITertiary tertiary { get; set; }
}
```

This still allows you to assign them classes

```
IRoot root = new Root {
    secondary = new Secondary(),
    tertiary = new Tertiary()
};
```

If, for some reason, you want to access members of the `Secondary` object that are not part of the `ISecondary` interface, you can do it like this:

```
var secondary = root.secondary as Secondary;
if (secondary != null) {
    secondary.DoSomething();
}
```

---

Quite another way is to use generics and generic type constraints

```
public interface IRoot<TSecondary, TTeritary>
    where TSecondary : ISecondary
    where TTeritary : ITertiary
{
    public TSecondary secondary
    public TTeritary tertiary
}
```

Then you can declare the two root classes like this

```
public class Root : IRoot<Secondary, Tertiary> 
{
    public Secondary secondary { get; set; }
    public Tertiary tertiary { get; set; }
}

public class Root2 : IRoot<Secondary2, Tertiary2> 
{
    public Secondary2 secondary { get; set; }
    public Tertiary2 tertiary { get; set; }
}
```

However, be aware that these two classes are not assignment compatible. The advantage is merely that a certain structure defined by the interface is enforced. If you really need assignment compatibility, drop the setters and use the `out` modifiers:

```
public interface IRoot<out TSecondary, out TTeritary>
    where TSecondary : ISecondary
    where TTeritary : ITertiary
{
    TSecondary secondary { get; }
    TTeritary tertiary { get; }
}
```

Now you can do this

```
var list = new List<IRoot<ISecondary, ITertiary>>();
list.Add(new Root());
list.Add(new Root2());
```

Comment: Generics are a stroke of genius. Thanks! I will try it out and see if it works with my program.

Comment: Yep! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Well, to implement the interface you have to use the same types, but you could keep the more specific implementation and implement the interface properties explicitly:

```
public class Root : IRoot
{
    public Secondary secondary { get; set; }
    public Tertiary tertiary { get; set; }
    public string foo { get; set; } // This wouldn't need to be cross-compatible

    ISecondary IRoot.secondary {get {return this.secondary;} set{;}}
    ITertiary IRoot.tertiary {get {return this.tertiary;} set{;}}
}
```

That way you can use the more sepcific types in a type-safe manner without casting.  The problem, however, is in the *setter* of `secondary` and `tertiary`.  Since you can pass in *any* `ISecondary`, there's no guaranttee that the object passed in is a `Secondary`, so you can't safely assign it to the `secondary` property.  Your options would be:

- Cast to a `Secondary`, which would throw an exception if it is not that type
- Determine if you *can* cast to `Secondary` and do something different if you can't
- Make the properties in `IRoot` get-only

Comment: @D Stanley - Do you have any good documentation this particular method of explicit interface property declaration? I'd like to learn more.

Comment: I've already seen this, it demonstrates explicit declaration of members, in this case, methods. Do you have something more detailed on properties?